# Is there any solution with elasticsearch parent-child join

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, aggregation

I have an es settings like following:

```
PUT /test
        {
        "mappings": {
         "doc": {
          "properties": {
            "status": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "counting": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "join": {
              "type": "join",
              "relations": {
                "vsim": ["pool", "package"]
              }
            },
            "poolId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "packageId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "countries": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "vId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
    }}
```

Then add data:

```
// add vsim
PUT /test/doc/doc1
{"counting":6, "join": {"name": "vsim"}, "content": "1", "status": "disabled"}

PUT /test/doc/doc2
{"counting":5,"join": {"name": "vsim"}, "content": "2", "status": "disabled"}

PUT /test/doc/doc3
{"counting":5,"join": {"name": "vsim"}, "content": "2", "status": "enabled"}

// add package
PUT /test/doc/ner2?routing=doc2
{"join": {"name": "package", "parent": "doc2"}, "countries":["CN", "UK"]}

PUT test/doc/ner12?routing=doc1
{"join": {"name": "package", "parent": "doc1"}, "countries":["CN", "US"]}

PUT /test/doc/ner11?routing=doc1
{"join":{"name": "package", "parent": "doc1"}, "countries":["US", "KR"]}

PUT /test/doc/ner13?routing=doc3
{"join":{"name": "package", "parent": "doc3"}, "countries":["UK", "AU"]}


// add pool
PUT /test/doc/ner21?routing=doc1
{"join": {"name": "pool", "parent": "doc1"}, "poolId": "MER"}

PUT /test/doc/ner22?routing=doc2
{"join": {"name": "pool", "parent": "doc2"}, "poolId": "MER"}

PUT /test/doc/ner23?routing=doc2
{"join": {"name": "pool", "parent": "doc2"}, "poolId": "NER"}
```

and then I want to count the counting group by the status(vsim), poolId(pool) and countries(package), the expect result like:

disabled-MER-CN: 3

disabled-MER-US: 3

enabled-MR-CN: 1
... and so on.
I'm a new player for elasticsearch, and I have learnt the document like

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html
and 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html

but still have no idea to implement this aggregation query, PLEASE give me some suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I followed your structure of the documents - you have types *pool* and *package* on the same level (they are siblings) - I wasn't able to achieve exactly your expected results. I also highly doubt that it's possible with those types being siblings.

However, it's still possible to slice per one field in your doc (**status**) and later separately slice both by *poolId* and *countries* with a query like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "status-aggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "to-pool": {
          "children": {
            "type": "pool"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top-poolid": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "poolId",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "to-package": {
          "children": {
            "type": "package"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top-countries": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "countries",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with a response from Elasticsearch like this (I've omitted some part of json for readability):

```
{
  "status-aggs": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "disabled",
        "doc_count": 2,
        "to-pool": {
          "doc_count": 3,
          "top-poolid": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "MER",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "NER",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "to-package": {
          "doc_count": 3,
          "top-countries": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "CN",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "US",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "KR",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "UK",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "enabled",
        "doc_count": 1,
        "to-pool": {
          "doc_count": 0,
          "top-poolid": {
            "buckets": []
          }
        },
        "to-package": {
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top-countries": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "AU",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "UK",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```